# Android getting value of db key of sql

Tags: android, sql

I'm trying to get the value in a specific column in my database and here's the code I have as of now to achieve it:

```
String id = db.KEY_ID;
```

but all I get now is the title of of the column, which in this case, id, instead of the value itself, such as 1, 2, etc. How do I grab the value and not the key of a database? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a query statement and execute it against the data base. You use `db.KEY_ID` to specify in the query what column of data you want.

Comment: I already had a query statement grabbing all the necessary data, but I can't grab the value of each column out instead I only get the name/key of each column, that's my issue

Answer (score 0):

A simple example:

```
public String getEntry(long rowIndex){
    String value = "";

        Cursor c = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_NAME, VALUE}, KEY_NAME + "=" + rowIndex, null, null, null, null);
        int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(VALUE);
        int rowsCount = c.getCount();
        if(rowsCount > 0){
                String value = c.getString(columnIndex);
        }

        return value;
}
```